# How to trigger without session access invalidate cart version

Tags: cart, cache, totals, section

On backend action (e.g. saving cart rule) I'd like to invalidate `customer/section/load` cartVersion to force Magento to recalculate totals on frontend on cart page for those who has that rule applied to his shopping cart.

Any ideas how?